# When are $z^n - 1$ and $(z+1)^n - 1$ relatively prime?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

The question and answer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3046766/81360) seem to imply that the polynomials $z^n - 1$ and $(z+1)^n - 1$ (over $\Bbb C[x])$ will be relatively prime if and only if $6 \nmid n$.

Is this true?  If so, is there a quick, direct justification that this is the case?

Comment: Shouldn't it be easy just to calculate the zeros of each and determine when those sets are disjoint?

Comment: For $n=6k$ we have
$$
gcd(z^n-1,(z+1)^n-1)=z^2+z+1.
$$

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42869/242) for much more general results.

Comment: @BillDubuque thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The geometric view. Not sure about an algebraic proof.

If they have a common factor, they have a common complex root.

If they have a common root, then there is some $n$th root of unity $\alpha$ such that $\alpha-1$ is also an $n$th root of unity.

Viewed on the unit circle, there are only two points where a horizontal chord on the unit circle has length equal to $1$, specifically the cases $y=\pm \sqrt{3}/2.$ 
These in turn yield $z$ to be one of the primitive sixth roots of unity.

---

Alternatively, the two unit circles $|z|=1$ and $|z+1|=1$ have two points in common. Those two points are the primitive cubed roots of $1.$ In those cases $z+1$ is a primitive sixth root of $1$ so we'd need $6\mid n.$

Comment: Moreover, this shows that in the case $6 \mid n$ the gcd is $z^2 + z + 1$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you

Comment: [An algebraic proof would be to find rational polynomials $p(z),q(z)$ such that $p(z)(z^n-1)+q(z)((z+1)^n-1)=z^2+z+1.$]