# What are the prime divisors of $\det(A_n)$, where $A_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix given by $(A_n)_{i,j}={n\choose|i-j|}$?

Tags: matrices, number-theory, binomial-coefficients, determinant, products

For $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$, let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix given by $(A_n)_{i,j}={n\choose |i-j|}$. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046766/find-the-determinant-of-the-n-times-n-matrix-a-n-with-a-n-i-j-n-choose) post it is clear that
$$\det(A_n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left[\left(\exp\left(\frac{2\pi k i}{n}\right)+1\right)^n-1\right]=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(2^n(-1)^k\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi k}n\right)-1\right).$$
Also, $\det(A_n)$ is obviously integer for all $n$, and $\det(A_n)=0$ iff $6\mid n$.

**Question:** What is known about the (prime) divisors of $\det(A_n)$?

If this is too broad, I am particularly interested in pairs $(p,d)$ where $p$ is prime with $d\mid p-1$ and $p\nmid\det(A_{(p-1)/d})$.

**Edit:** It seems like the product with cosines in it is integer independent of the exponent, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048327/are-elementary-symmetric-polynomials-evaluated-in-powers-of-double-cosines-of-ra) question of mine.

**Edit 2:** The first few values of $\det A_n$ are:
\begin{align*}
 \det(A_1) &= 1\\
 \det(A_2) &= -3=-(2^2-1)\cdot 1^2\\
 \det(A_3) &= 28 = (2^3-1)\cdot2^2\\
 \det(A_4) &= -375 = (2^4-1)\cdot5^2\\
 \det(A_5) &= 3751 = (2^5-1)\cdot11^2\\
 \det(A_6) &= 0\\
 \det(A_7) &= 6835648 = (2^7-1)\cdot232^2\\
 \det(A_8) &=-1343091375 = -(2^8-1)\cdot2295^2\\
\det(A_9) &= 364668913756 = (2^9-1)\cdot26714^2
\end{align*}

**Edit 3:** It looks like this is called 'Wendt's determinant'. My entire motivation for asking this question had to do with a possible proof for Fermat's last theorem and this link is apparently known as 'Wendt's theorem'

Comment: It looks like $\det(A_n)=(-1)^{n+1}(2^n-1)m(n)^2$ for some $m:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $m(n)$ must be the product over $0<2k<n$.

Comment: @metamorhpy. Oh, nevermind, I got it. Also, if $d\mid k$, then $\det A_d\mid \det A_k$

Comment: I found http://oeis.org/search?q=232%2C2295&language=english&go=Search

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A048954 and https://oeis.org/A215615